# How to take trigonometric functions from the console with sympy?

Tags: python, math, sympy, trigonometry, differential-equations

Im trying to make a code for differential equations the method reduction of order, and when I try to put a trigonometric function the next error appears.

```
SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse 'sin x'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Can you please help me?
here's the code!

```
def DividirFuncion(expr):
    
    P1T = expr [0]
    newExpr = []

    for i in range(len(expr)):
      NuevEle = expr[i]/P1T
      newExpr.append(NuevEle)
    
    return newExpr

def main():
    x = symbols("x")
    EDO = []
    #Pide cada uno de los terminos

    dy2= sympify(input("Dame y'' "))
    dy1=sympify(input ("Dame y' "))
    dy = sympify(input("Dame y "))

    EDO.append(dy2)
    EDO.append(dy1)
    EDO.append(dy)


    Y1 = sympify(input("Ingresa el valor inicial de y1: "))

    #Manda llamar la función para dividir 
    Edo2 = DividirFuncion(EDO)
    
    dPx = Edo2[1] #Designamos Px
    P = integrate(dPx) #Se integra Px
    
    k = exp(-P)/(Y1**2) 

    if k == 1:
      y2 = Y1 * integrate(k,x)

    else:
      y2 = Y1 * integrate(k)


    print("\n\tEl resultado final es:", y2)
```

Comment: Try `sin(x)` instead of `sin x`.

Comment: te amooo ya jalo!!!!